Why does Quine's argument threaten logical truths?
At the end of this video on Quine's critique of the analytic/synthetic distinction,  there is an argument about why logical truths are suspect, because of Quine's critique:

Quine's argument also threatens the idea of logical truths -- what
Quine called analytic statements of the first class [...] [Quine]
grants logical truths. But we might think that there is a bit of a
problem here. Let's take a logical truth of the form $∀x (Vx → Vx)$ or
"if x is a vixen then x is a vixen" or more colloquially "all vixens
are vixens"... but this only works if each instance of "vixen" has the
same meaning. If the first token of vixens means female foxes and
the second token of vixens means attractive women, then obviously
this statement is false.
Ordinarily, we would say that this kind of thing is not a counter
example to logical truths because it would be equivocating on the term
vixen. When we characterize logical truths we have to specify the
different tokens of the same expression have the same meaning. It must
be the first token of vixen is synonymous with the second token of
vixen. Without sameness of meaning it is not quite so obvious how we
are to understand logical truths.

I have a bit of a trouble interpreting what is being said above. Specifically, what does the speaker mean when he says If the first token of vixens means female foxes and the second token of vixens means attractive women, then obviously this statement is false? What is the first and second token in the sentence "all vixens are vixens", and why they can have different meanings? I understand how in general in our language the word "vixen" might have different meanings, but how can it change in a sentence such as "if x is a vixen then x is a vixen"? To me, when I read the sentence the word "vixen" represents a label of some category, it doesn't matter how the category is defined or whether the definition is correct. What matters is that there is a definition and it has the label "vixen" slapped on it and x might match that definition or not.

The purported counterexample is based on the fact (undeniable) that some words have different meanings that we can understand only in the context of the speech.

@KristianBerry For me, the problem lies in applying logic to analyze propositions in natural language. The two frameworks operate completely differently. In logic, terms are defined before being used; in natural language, terms are used before being defined. In the former, this is done to avoid ambiguity, while in the latter, clarity is sacrificed for speed. If natural language operated like logic, we would instead say, 'given that a vixen is a female fox, all vixens are vixens'.

@KristianBerry actually, I should have said that in natural language terms are lazy defined -- defined on request for clarification or simply left for the reader.

@KristianBerry so basically all v are v where v = vixen -- even if v is defined prior its use, the definition can mean different things and therefore v can mean different things?

@KristianBerry if you want you can make an answer based on what you have said, and I would accept it, since it seems to have answered my original question best.

Quine's arguments against analyticity do not apply to logical truths - at least from Quine's perspective on the subject.
For Quine, logic is rooted in grammar. Logic is concerned with structural features of language. Some words or phrases can be identified as 'logical particles' and are distinguished from other words and phrases that are not. We can recognise that a sentence such as "no unmarried man is married" is a logical truth without having to understand the meaning of 'married' or 'man'. What makes it a logical truth is not some fact about meanings, but the fact that the sentence is true if we uniformly subsitute other words for 'married' or for 'man'.
Quine prefers not to speak of meanings, since he considers the concept to be too vague to provide a foundation for logic. He thinks of logic in terms of substitutivity. Logical truths remain true under uniform substitution of words other than the logical particles. By contrast, the sentence, "no bachelor is married" is not a logical truth since it does not remain true if we substitute 'bachelor' or 'married' separately. Hence his criticisms of analyticity do not carry over to logical truths.
While it might be possible for someone to utter the sentence, "all vixens are vixens," with the intended sense that all female foxes are bad-tempered women, it would be a very odd thing to do. I suspect Quine would say that the sentence is being used in a specific contextual fashion that the audience would recognise as different from the conventional logical truth through its inferential consequences.

From Conifold:

The point of Quine's critique is that meaning is an ephemeral notion that cannot be pinned down in a non-circular way, i.e. without appealing to equivalents like synonymy or analyticity. And if we cannot pin down "the same meaning" then what sense does it make for the "meaning" of different instances of "vixen" to be the "same"? It is not even clear what "changing the meaning" is about considering that there is no tangible entity to do the changing in the first place. "Defining a category" does not help because the "defining" is done in terms of other categories with the same problem.

